# Image Upload not working

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I recently upgraded my server to PHP 5.6 from 5.4.

Now Magento freezes and times out when I try to upload product images. I never get to upload them. It just freezes after browsing and selecting the images.

`Magento 1.9.2`

Also it could be the new patch I applied recently?

Comment: please do a cross browser check

Comment: Hi, I have tried both Firefox and Google Chrome with same result

Comment: please check this folder skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/ and see the swf files are there

Comment: -r--------  1 www-data www-data 266207 Mar  6  2016 editor.swf

Comment: @DennisW please dlt those swf files if you applied security patch 8788 and then try again uploading

Comment: I have deleted the editor.swf files, that was the only one in the folder. Then cleared the cache but still no luck

Comment: Firefox tells me that lib/uploader/flow.min.js is hanging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please max_execution_time in your configuration setting its needs to Max. Also please check respective files and folder permissions are set to correct one, then refresh cache.

Comment: My max_execution_time is set to 720 (I tried 1800). I have followed the "recommended permissions from the documentation" and cleared the cache. Both on Magento and cloudflare that I am using. But still no luck. It just freezes and crashed the browser tab after some time

Comment: It was actually the max post size. I accept the answer as it lead me to the other settings. Thanks!